# Get IP address of server from Response in okhttp3

Tags: java, okhttp

I'm using okhttp3 and am trying to get the Ip address of the server that I am contacting, (for logging reasons).

Ideally I'd like to be able to receive a response, and grab the IPV4 or IPV6 address from the server that the response came from. Looking through okhttp3 docs I don't see an obvious way.

Is this possible? Or is there perhaps another way to get this information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write an Interceptor that adds the IP address as an HTTP header in the response. You can get this information from the `connection` which is on the `chain` of a network interceptor. Note that this IP address will apply to cached responses also.

See the Interceptors doc for samples.
https://square.github.io/okhttp/features/interceptors/